# yii file upload Exception

Tags: yii

When I upload files in `Yii` using the following code it generates an error.

```
$file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
```

and the error goes here.
[YiiBase::include(Upload.php) [function.YiiBase-include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory]

I think a minor thing is being missed by my while configuring `Yii`.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Whats you model's class? and where is it located?

Comment: Do you Yii::import() the Upload class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you specify the enctype in your form ? 
i.e for example:

```
CHtml::beginForm('', 'post', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));
```

if it's not specified the file won't be uploaded.